# How do I fix small chips and scratches in a melamine table top?

Tags: melamine, scratches

Below is what I am talking about. How do I fix these ?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scratches that are not all the way through the surface you can polish out, or sand out and leave a matte surface that will not show scratches so easily.

Chips can, at best, be filled with something that never quite matches, or you replace the table-top, as it's the only actual fix for those, IMPE. The canonical product that never quite matches is called "Seam-fil" evidently.

The simplest effective solution is called a tablecloth.

Comment: +1 for "The simplest effective solution is called a tablecloth".

Comment: Thanks guys. What do I use for polishing. Tablecloth does not really work for a coffee table